# Running a virtual machine on a CentOS server

Tags: centos, virtualization

I need to install a guest virtual machine on top of a remote CentOS server host. I can access my host machine through ssh terminal only and I prefer using CentOS native packages only. My guest VM is binary is i386 based but the host is x86_64.

**Edit >>>**

I am running the guest for testing only so performance is not an issue. My guest should have bridged network interface to one of my existing ethX ports in my host

**<<< Edit**

Which virtual machine software you recommend for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KVM should work fine (probably managed using libvirt and friends).  It's integrated into the latest releases of RHEL (and hence CentOS) 5.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox can fit your requirements as an option to consider.

Comment: but VirtualBox is not a prat of *official* CentOS

Comment: It's not, but Sun/Oracle does have specific builds for RHEL/CentOS.